# Frustrated with correct architecture of ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I tried to create one more new ASP.NET MVC application (with Entity Framework) and a little frustrated again.

For example, I have a database with the following tables:

Table Users:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Title] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [Company] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Phone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

[CompanyUrl] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [EmailPlainText] [bit] NULL,
 [ProfileImage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ProfileDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ProfileDocument] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ProfileWebSite] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Facebook] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Linkedin] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [MySpace] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Twitter] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Services](
 [ServiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ServiceName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 [ServiceOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Services] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserServices](
 [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ServiceID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserServices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeographicalAreas](
 [GeoAreaID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [GeoAreaName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GeographicalAreas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserGeoAreas](
 [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [GeoAreaID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserGeoAreas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

so, how can we see, there is : one table for User info, 2 table-dictionaries (Services and GeographicalAreas) and 2 tables  (UserServices and UserGeoAreas) for relationship many-to-many between User and table-dictionaries. Standard situation

Also we have 3 different pages :

1. On the first page should be displayed :

FirstName, LastName, Title, Company, Services (linked to an user) and GeoAreas (linked to an user)

1. On the second page:

FirstName, LastName, Title, Company, Facebook, Linkedin and Twitter

1. On the third page only FirstName, LastName, ProfileImage and ProfileDocument

Also, on the filrst page should be validate attributes like "required" etc

so, how to realize it?

The first way:

Creating 3 different view-classes (3 different models) for each page, creating 3 different linq-requests (3 public methods in a class-repository), each method of controller (for each page) calls the appropriate method in class-repository

The second way:

Create one common view class (which includes all requires fields for 3 pages), one common method in a class-repository, which fills all fields, each method of controller calls the method of repository

The third way:

Creating 3 different view-classes (3 different models) for each page, one common class (which includes all requires fields for 3 pages), one method in a class-repository, which fills all fields, 3 converters to move data from the common class to the appropriate view-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, go with the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every object should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

Your option 1 would be the correct one. Every view should have its own distinct controller and its own distinct view model (ideally being retrieved by its own distinct call to a repository).

Comment: but then we have to create 3 similar view classes (imagine 3 classes, which have approx 30 fields and these fields the same for 90%), have to change in each class if we change model at all (i.e. adding new field to DB) and 3 similar linq-requests.

Comment: also is it necessary to create repository class in this case or it would be better to make requests to _dbcontext directly in a controller class?

Comment: It's a trade-off. On one hand you have various similar classes, on the other hand you don't have to remember all the places where one class is being used when one view must be modified. It always comes down to how complicated it becomes once you have to change something. The rule of thumb is: One model per view. Concerning the repository: `DbContext` itself behaves like a repository. Putting a custom repository on top introduces complexity and should not be done without a good reason. But that is my opinion, others' might differ.

Comment: some words about Repository. I.e. the same request used 2 times in different places. So, it would be better to move it to separate clas